# Form does not allow uploads

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm currently working on a symfony2 form that would allow the user to add pictures when he creates an article. I created a form that looks like this :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('price')
        ->add('size')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('pictures', 'collection', array(
        'type' => new PictureType(),
        'allow_add' => true,
        'by_reference' => false,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'prototype' => true

    ));
}
```

Thing is, when I use this one, my form does not allow to upload any picture (I can add name, price, size, description, but the "add files" button is nowhere to be found).Picture entity looks like this :

```
class Picture
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
private $id;

/**
* @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
*/
public $file;

/**
* @var string
*
* @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
* @var string
*
* @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=255)
*/
private $path;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="pictures")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="property_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $article;
```

Form is displayed like this :

```
            <form method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>

                <br/>
                <h1>NEW ARTICLE</h1>
                {{ form_widget(form) }}
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary send_message" />
            </form>
```

and this is PictureType

```
class PictureType extends AbstractType
{
 /**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
     $builder->add('name','text',array(
        "label" => "Name",
        "required" => TRUE,
    ));
    $builder->add('description','textarea',array(
        "label" => "Description",
        "required" => FALSE,
    ));
    $builder->add('files','file',array(
        "label" => "Fichiers",
        "required" => FALSE,
        "attr" => array(
            "accept" => "image/*",
            "multiple" => "multiple",
        )
    ));
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Dyma\DesignerBundle\Entity\Picture'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'dyma_designerbundle_picture';
}
}
```

This is the first time I ever use a collection in a form, so I'm not even sure what it should look like, but I'm pretty sure something is wrong with my code. Any idea why I can't add these pictures ?

Comment: show us your form in the view

Comment: <form method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>

 <br/>
     <h1>NEW ARTICLE</h1>
  {{ form_widget(form) }}
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary send_message" />
    </form>

Hard to make it easier :)

Comment: I think @Dai wants to see the form_enctype that is displayed. If its not multipart it won't be able to upload files at all.

Comment: @Chilion , I 'm not sure I understand what you mean. I replaced the form with <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" {{ form_enctype(form) }}> , still doesn't display anything to upload files.

Comment: you should show PictureType, since it contains the field with your problem.

Comment: Done. I added every possible detail to make it work, still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You should (as stated in comments) add a `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form.

Besides that,

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

Comment: did both. the enctype didn't change a thing, and the input, obviously, added an input field for upload, but it has nothing to do with the form, and the selected files are not uploaded

Comment: I assume you know that you should save the file yourself? A user posts it to the form and you are doing the rest of the work. You know that...?

Comment: Yes I do. At first, I tried to do so with just one file, it worked just fine (no need to add a file input, still had the button generated automatically by the form). Then, I tried to change it to allow multiple uploads at the same time, so I changed the file to a collection of files. Though, telling by your answer, I assume it is not possible, so I'll do it the hard way...

Comment: I guess you could have asked a more detailed question. If I get it right, you want to upload multiple files using the Symphony 2 framework?

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry, I try to be as precise as possible, but english is not my native language and I struggle when it comes to technical terms. I looked for answers for 3 days now, and the thing is, every other multi-upload code I found so far seems to be exactly as mine. I might sound dumb, but, once I created a symfony2 form, isn't the twig template {{form(form)}} supposed to generate every part of my form ? Including the file-upload input ?

Comment: That depends on the input you give to form. I never work with Twig or whatsoever any templating engine for several reasons, not knowing what exactly happens (like in your case) is one of the main reasons. I'm sorry, but as I stated, I don't know Twig, so I can't help you any further :(